# Can a Highcharts Donut or Pie Chart Show a Default Background Circle?

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am helping my organization put together some Pie and Donut charts using Highcharts, and some of our charts will have zero value points.  Normal behavior is to not render these points out, but that leaves us with an empty chart.

So, is there a way to set a "background" circle for the Donut chart so that if all values are zero, the user still sees a gray donut (indicating "0" values)?

I don't want to use something like a background image because then it may not adjust responsively in a proper manner.  Plus, we'd like the parameters of the circle to be adjustable just like other data elements in Highcharts.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: Maybe better is use kind of "fake point" with value i.e 1 instead of 0 which is not printed?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, so I would hide the "fake point" unless the others=0 ?